# Accessing a list of class from within another class - null reference exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have a class which creates a list of another class.
which looks like:

```
class SortItAll
{                                       
    Recipient rec;
    public List<Recipient> listofRec = new List<Recipient>();

    public void sortToClass()
    {
        while (isThereNextLine()) { //while there is a following line
            loadNextLine();         //load it

            rec = new Recipient(loadNextPiece(),  //break that line to pieces and send them as arguments to create an instance of "Recipient" class
                                loadNextPiece(),
                                loadNextPiece(),
                                loadNextPiece());
            listofRec.Add(rec);                   //add the created instance to my list
        }
    }
```

From my Form1 class I call this method (sortToClass()), which by my logic should fill my list with that specific class. Then I want to write the list.count() to a textbox:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        SortItAll sort = new SortItAll(); //create the instance of the class

        sort.sortToClass();               //within which i call the method to fill my list

        txt_out.Text = sort.listofRec.Count().ToString(); //writing out its count to a textbox

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And now my problem is whenever I try to debug, it stops me with a

```
Nullreference exception pointing to -> "txt_out.Text = sort.listofRec.Count().ToString();" in Form1.
```

Yet, while debugging I can check the locals, where it states:

```
sort -> listOfRec -> Count = 4.
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Is txt_out what is null?

Comment: Try running the code _after_ the call to `InitializeComponent`; that should make sure all the controls (like `txt_out`) are initialized I think.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put

```
 txt_out.Text = sort.listofRec.Count().ToString(); //writing out its count to a textbox
```

after InitializeComponent(), since it's created in that method.

Comment: I just realized indeed I've to call the method after InitializeComponent. been thinking about this like 2 hours :/ I'm a retard. thanks to you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should keep `InitializeComponent();` at the top of the method as it creates all the controls on the form.  You are probably getting it because you are trying to access control `txt_out` before it has been created and added to the form.